# Implementing a counter using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input>   
<Properties>
  <Type Name="Type1">
    <Property NAME="Prop1"/>
    <Property NAME="Prop2"/>
    <Property NAME="Prop3"/>
  </Type>
  <Type Name="Type2">
    <Property NAME="Prop4"/>
    <Property NAME="Prop5"/>
  </Type>
  <Type Name="Type3">
    <Property NAME="Prop6"/>
  </Type>
  <Type Name="Type4">
    <Property NAME="Prop7"/>
    <Property NAME="Prop8"/>
  </Type>
  <Type Name="Type5">
    <Property NAME="Prop9"/>
  </Type>
</Properties>
 </Input>
```

I need to implement a counter using xslt that will give me the total Property count under all types (in this case 9 ). Can it be done in xslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to implement a counter using xslt that will give me the total
>   Property count under all types (in this case 9 ).

**No, you don't need to implement a counter**.

**Just use**:

```
count(/*/*/Type/Property)
```

To answer your next question:

> Can it be done in xslt?

**No, mutable variables are not possible in a functional language** (a category to which XSLT belongs) -- by definition. And having mutable variables is not necessary.

Any problem that can be solved in an imperative way (with mutable variables), can also be solved in a functional way -- without using mutable variables.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre. I will have to get started with the concepts of functional language.

Comment: @MartinKahn, You are welcome. I recommend some of the books on XSLT and XPath contained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305